# Como Criar uma array a partir de trechos de texto de uma string?

Tags: javascript, array

Alguém poderia me ajudar, com algum método, função ou o que for disponível, pra fazer com que uma string se torne uma array feita de pedaços da mesma string exemplo:

```
var string = "stackoverflow";
var array = [];
console.log(array) // ['stack'], ['over'], ['flow']
```

e/ou

```
var string = "gameoveragain";
var array = [];
console.log(array) // ['game'], ['over'], ['again']'
```

bem é isso que eu quero como nos exemplos, algo onde eu posso reutilizar, e que sempre encontra o trecho 'over' na string e a partir disso a string se torne uma array separada, no caso, ela pode ser uma array com 3 itens 2, 1 ou vários, se no caso sempre for encontrado especificamente 'over' dentro da string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const split = function (string) {
    string = string.split(/(over)/);
    return string;
};
```

O método `.split()` vai separar uma `string` em `substrings` e retornar um `array`. O parâmetro que eu passo entre parêntesis é o parâmetro de separação da `string`, ou seja, o método irá dividir a `string` quande ele for encontrado.

No caso eu passei de parâmetro uma regex para poder capturar o grupo e adicioná-lo ao `array` de retorno.

Para aprender mais sobre regex, recomendo:

http://aprenda.vidageek.net/aprenda/regex

Para quem entende inglês melhor aula de regex do YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YEypLuls7iidwHMdCM6o2w

Comment: Boa `+1`! Podes explicar como é que o split funciona neste caso com eregx? Assim a resposta fica mais completa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e recomendações de links de estudos, realmente estou precisando aprender muito isso, o algorítimo é muito simples, eu só não entendi bem como que o split funciona com o regex, antes de fazer a pergunta aqui, eu já tentei fazer algo usando o split, mas não obtive sucesso, mas vou estudar seus links pra entender, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma alternativa mais reaproveitável.

```js
var _split= function (text, term) {
  var index = 0;
  var terms = [];
  text.replace(new RegExp(term, "gi"), function (term, i) {
    terms.push(text.substring(index, i));
    terms.push(term);
    index = i + term.length;
  });
  terms.push(text.substring(index));
  return terms;
}

var terms = _split("stackoverflowovergame", "over");
console.log(terms);
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta!